# How to turn specific tags in soup to strings?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Suppose i have a tag called 'title' I saw  a way to turn a specific tag to string using  soup.title.string

but when i have a few tags with the same name i didnt find a way to turn them to string.  I used findall by id but i cant convert to string

```
url = 'http://rollersadnessstranded.com'
req = requests.get(url)
html = req.text
soup = (BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser'))
x=soup.find_all('title', attrs={'id':'description'})
```

How do i convert x to string?

I cant use there .string nor get text

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through them and `str()` each one of them.

```
url = 'http://rollersadnessstranded.com'
req = requests.get(url)
html = req.text
soup = (BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser'))
tags = soup.find_all('title', attrs={'id':'description'})

tags = [str(tag) for tag in tags]
```

`tags` is now a list of all tags as strings

Comment: thx. but this would turn the entire oject into string i need only the content itself as string .your output gives '[<meta content="Search the world\'s information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you\'re looking for." name="description"/>]' i just want  "Search the world\'s information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you\'re looking for"

Comment: oh I misunderstood you. Then, try this: replace `str(tag)` with `str.text` or `str.contents` or `str.content`. I'm not sure which one will work, I don't have access html you want to process.

Comment: if you meant tag.content tag.text in your example they do no work